# How to notify a UserControl when my tcpListener parse a response?

Tags: c#, wpf, tcp, event-handling

I'm building a basic TCP client/server application using C# and wpf.
I'm trying to notify a user control (a button in my case) when the client parse a response from the server.

As I understand, I have to create a event in my TcpClient class which will be fired when the response is parsed, and I have to subscribe my button to this event and use Dispatcher.Invoke(). But I have no clues about how to implement it, and MSDN doc didn't helped me.
I've use the MSDN examples below for server and client to "PoC" it :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

On my MainWindow I've a Button "test_btn". I wand to update the content of the button to "Success" when I parse my response from the server.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

MainWindow.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Thread TcpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AsynchronousClient.StartClient));
    TcpThread.Start();

}
```

AsynchronousClient.cs:

```
Receive(client);
receiveDone.WaitOne();

// Write the response to the console.  
Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);
if(response == "success)
{
 // Update the button from the MainWindow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come to answer by myself.

If it can help somebody :

I've added in my MainWindow.cs:

```
public delegate void updateNetworkButtonDelegate(string message);
public void updateNetworkButton(string message)
{
    if (!test_btn.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        test_btn.Dispatcher.Invoke(new updateNetworkButtonDelegate(updateNetworkButton), message);
    }
    else
    {
       test_btn.Content = message;
    }
}
```

}

I've modify my TcpClient to pass the MainWindow in param :

```
 public static void StartClient(MainWindow mw)
```

then I could update my button with :

mw.updateNetworkButton(response);